# NuGet Packages Missing And Unable to Restore After Checking Out Test Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, nunit, nuget-package-restore

I recently added an NUnit 3 Unit Test project for Xamarin.Android into my app's solution in Visual Studio 2019.  I was able to configure it and get it running (successfully with some tests, even!), but as soon as I checked the project into our repository and pulled it to a new machine, I'm unable to get it working in any capacity that I've tried.  Every time I try to build, I'm presented with the error "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing from this computer."  The packages are definitely available in the project directory, and NuGet Package Manager seems to recognize that they are there.

So far, I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the packages through NuGet Package Manager
- Trying `Update-Package -Reinstall` in the PM console
- Trying `Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName myProject` in PM console and specifically targeting the test project.
- Trying `Update-Package -Reinstall -Safe` in PM console
- Manually modifying `.csproj` with .dll directories for package references.

After each of these, I was presented with the same error.  "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing from this computer."  I know for a fact they aren't.  What am I missing here?  In addition, am I going to have to go through this process every time that the project is pulled to a new machine?

**Update:**

After some trial and error, I was able to build the test project, deploy it to a virtual device and run it successfully by following these steps:

1. In the Explorer view of the project in Visual Studio, I deleted the 'packages' folder in the root directory of the project.
2. I opened a Package Manager Console window to try `Update-Package -Reinstall` again, but this time the PM console window had a prompt telling me that Visual Studio noticed that there were referenced packages missing, and if I wanted to Restore them.  I clicked 'Restore' and waited for the task to complete.

   At this point I was able to build successfully, but when attempting to deploy to a virtual Android device, I was presented with an error: "The LinkAssemblies task has failed unexpectedly."
3. I installed the latest available Android SDK (API 28, Android Pie), and changed the Target Framework of the test project to match.

This has me successfully running my NUnit test app on the Android emulator, but my concern now is that if I push any changes to origin, the next machine that tries to pull the project down will encounter the same issues I did.  I suppose this updates the focus of my original question to: **what have I done wrong to cause myself this problem, and how can I prevent it from carrying over to other machines that need to pull the project?**

Comment: Something that works for me most of the time is deleting both *obj* and *bin* directories under the project folder. Keep VS closed while doing this. Also, when you open the project for the first time try to give some time for the packages to update before hitting on "Compile/Run"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  This unfortunately did not work for me.  I've gotten to the point where I'm at least able to run my test app now, and I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: You can post your solution to answer, it will help others who have similar.